# Change table content using a link

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am new to PHP and I made a simple program where you can apply your name and age, it will take the data to the database and the table will be added with a new row.
I want to add a new column where you can click "change", only the data from that particular row will show up in a few textboxes and can be changed. when pressing submit I want to use the UPDATE function to update the records.

**example/plot:**

- Mike Towards 23 Change
- Tyler Frankenstein 24
- Change Sophie Baker 22
  Change

I want to change the age of Sophie Baker to 24 so I press Change on that row.
Now I only want to get the data from that row and make some changes.

The code I have this far:

Drawing the table above the input fields and the input:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");

echo "<table border='2'> <tr> <th>Voornaam</th> <th>Achternaam</th> <th>Leeftijd</th></tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Age'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>

<html>
<body>
    <br />
    <form action="insert.php" method="post"><br />
    <input type="text" name="firstname"> Firstname <br />
    <input type="text" name="lastname"> Lastname <br />
    <input type="text" name="age"> Age
    <p><input type="submit"></p>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Parser:

```
 <?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user" , "", "personInfo");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age) VALUES ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[age]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added to the database";
echo "<p><a href=sql2.php>Back to form</a></p>";

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

I have tried a few things, but I cant figure out how to show the content on the row I want to select.
Change the actual data with the update function won't be the problem, so I only need help to get the actual data from the correct row.

Comment: you should add the table schema of Persons table. you'd need to select with the primary key of that table if any exists. if not you should create one.

Comment: using mysqli_* functions is good, but it would be even better to use prepared statements for your inserts query :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'd need to select with the primary key of that table if any exists. if not you should create one. I assume you have a primary key named PersonID:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE PersonID = '" . ($_GET['PersonID']) . "'";
```

to add the edit button:

```
echo "<table border='2'> <tr> <th>Voornaam</th> <th>Achternaam</th> <th>Leeftijd</th><th>Action</th></tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Age'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><a href = '?PersonID=" . $row['PersonID'] . "'>Edit</a></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Aah! how could I not have figured that out. I already have an idea now about how I want to do this now. I made the ID within the table so I can easily work with this solution. Thanks!

Comment: I have to wait a few minutes, then I will tick this post as the correct answer.

Comment: Volkan Ulukut, I get an error on this line: 
$query = "SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE PID = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['PID']) . "'"; Perhaps you know what I can do to fix it. It's this error: Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given

Comment: oh sorry you'd need to add $con identifier. but isn't important for a primary field. just remove it. edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a column named "id".

you can do the following:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user" , "", "personInfo");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

    // when you are in "edit mode" just display the row you will edit row
    if (isset($_GET['id'])
      $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons where id = ".(int)$_GET['id']);
    else
  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");

echo "<table border='2'> <tr> <th>Voornaam</th> <th>Achternaam</th> <th>Leeftijd</th></tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Age'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><a href='?id=" . $row['id'] . "'>change</a></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>

<html>
<body>
    <br />
    <form action="update.php" method="post"><br />
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['id']?$_GET['id']:'') ?>" />
        <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo isset($row['FirstName'])?$row['FirstName']:'' ?>"/> Firstname <br />
        <input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php echo isset($row['LastName'])?$row['LastName']:'' ?>"/> Lastname <br />
        <input type="text" name="age" value="<?php echo isset($row['Age'])?$row['Age']:'' ?>"/> Age
    <p><input type="submit"></p>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

update.php (handle both insertion and update):

```
 <?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user" , "", "personInfo");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
    if (isset($_POST['id'])
      $sql="UPDATE Persons set FirstName = ?, LastName = ?, Age = ? 
        WHERE id = ".(int)$_POST['id'];
    else
      $sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

    $sth = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);
    $sth->bind_param($_POST[firstname],$_POST[lastname],$_POST[age]);

if (!$sth->execute())
{
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record ".(isset($_POST['id']?'modified':'added')." to the database";
echo "<p><a href=sql2.php>Back to form</a></p>";
```

Comment: Also a very nice solution, I might use some parts of this answer as well! thanks.

Comment: it's to show you the prepared statements: the prepare() and bind_param() protect you against someone you could type something like `1'; TRUNCATE TABLE Persons;` to delete all your datas

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It's always nice to learn new things.

Comment: The php from the html textfield does not work correctly. It shows the actual php code within the fields. I can't figure out what the problem is. I tried a few things in the meanwhile.

Comment: sorry, I written `<php?` instead of `<?php`, I wasn't thinking when I wrote that :s . Oh, and I forgot to mention it would be better to write the html & body (and doctype) tags before any other output ( like the `echo '<table>';`)